# Calling Comments to Populate a TableView: correcting code errors

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to populate a my commentsTable with the comments from my posts. I have the following Database structure JSON:

```
  {
  "posts" : {
    "-Lhu-XRs806sXSEQS2BF" : {
      "reports" : 0,
      "text" : "How can I improve my data structure?",
      "timestamp" : 1561120090116,
      "title" : "Hello Stack Exchange",
      "userID" : "nyRBXSyyDhc1Qkypou0Iz0iMsyr1"
    },
    "-Lhu-fI6DMSZvy8EdIgM" : {
      "reports" : 0,
      "text" : "As in Libre",
      "timestamp" : 1561120126347,
      "title" : "Free",
      "userID" : "nyRBXSyyDhc1Qkypou0Iz0iMsyr1"
    },
    "comments" : {
      "-Lhu-hXISy-0N2V4ES-a" : {
        "reports" : 0,
        "timestamp" : 1561120135594,
        "userID" : "nyRBXSyyDhc1Qkypou0Iz0iMsyr1"
      },
      "-Lhu-j1cR6V407tyUYY1" : {
        "reports" : 0,
        "timestamp" : 1561120141801,
        "userID" : "nyRBXSyyDhc1Qkypou0Iz0iMsyr1"
      },
      "-Lhu-lrJp9H8SQowlYWz" : {
        "reports" : 0,
        "timestamp" : 1561120153314,
        "userID" : "nyRBXSyyDhc1Qkypou0Iz0iMsyr1"
      },
      "posts" : {
        "-Lhu-XRs806sXSEQS2BF" : {
          "comments" : {
            "-Lhu-hXISy-0N2V4ES-_" : "How is it going?",
            "-Lhu-j1cR6V407tyUYY0" : "It’s good to see you"
          }
        },
        "-Lhu-fI6DMSZvy8EdIgM" : {
          "comments" : {
            "-Lhu-lrJp9H8SQowlYWy" : "Richard Stallman"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the following Comment class:

```
class Comment {
    var id:String
    var text:String

    init(id: String, text:String) {
        self.id = id
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

Here is my code after taking your suggestions into account:

```
var comments = [Comment] ()
@IBOutlet weak var commentsTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var commentPlaceHolder: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var newCommentLabel: UITextView!
weak var delegate:NewPostVCDelegate?
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

@IBAction func reply(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let userID = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
    addComment(toPostId: post!.id, andComment: newCommentLabel.text, commentByUid: userID)
    loadComments(forPostId: post!.id)
    comments.removeAll()
    commentsTable.reloadData()
    newCommentLabel.text = String()
    commentPlaceHolder.isHidden = false
}

func addComment(toPostId: String, andComment: String, commentByUid: String) {
    let commentsRef = self.ref.child("comments") //ref to the comments node
    let thisCommentRef = commentsRef.child(toPostId) //ref to a node with postId as key
    let commentToAddRef = thisCommentRef.childByAutoId() //each comment will have it's own key
    let d = [
        "comment_text": andComment,
        "comment_by_uid": commentByUid]
    commentToAddRef.setValue(d)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    loadComments(forPostId: post!.id)
}

func loadComments(forPostId: String) {
    let ref = self.ref.child("comments")
    let thisPostRef = ref.child(forPostId)
    thisPostRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        let allComments = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for commentSnap in allComments {
            let commenterUid = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "comment_by_uid").value as? String ?? "No uid"
            let commentText = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "comment_text").value as? String ?? "No comment"
            let aComment = Comment(id: commenterUid, text: commentText)
            self.comments.append(aComment)
            print(commenterUid, commentText)
        }
        self.commentsTable.reloadData()
    })
}

func adjustUITextViewHeight(arg : UITextView) {
    arg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    arg.sizeToFit()
    arg.isScrollEnabled = false
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.commentsTable.dataSource = self
    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "CommentTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    commentsTable.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")
    view.addSubview(commentsTable)
    commentsTable.register(LoadingCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "loadingCell")

    self.commentsTable.delegate = self
    mainText.isEditable = false
    titleText.isEditable = false
    commentsTable.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")
    view.addSubview(commentsTable)
    commentsTable.register(LoadingCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "loadingCell")
    print(delegate!)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return comments.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
        cell.set(comment: comments[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "loadingCell", for: indexPath) as! LoadingCell
        cell.spinner.startAnimating()
        return cell
    }
}

func textViewDidChange(_ commentView: UITextView) {
    commentPlaceHolder.isHidden = !newCommentLabel.text.isEmpty
}
```

Incorporating Jay's comments, I got the view running. I had to add comments.removAll() so it did not print out the comments multiple times in the commentsTable. However, the `func textViewDidChange` no longer functions. I am not sure how to address this. I tried calling the function with no luck. Maybe the delegate change affected this?

Comment: Your main problem is `let comment = Comment(id: childDataSnapshot.key, text: comments)` you should pass `text` not `comments`

Comment: I am not sure how to call each comment text as each one is associated with a unique id like "-Lht1KEhkJR7ZPTcDqn8" or "-Lht1M76Bu9kTXJDezPp"

Comment: I deleted my answer. Apart from the errors the entire JSON parsing cannot work for example there is no `id` key in the JSON at all. And it's unclear how the user IDs are related to the `-Lht...` dictionary keys.

Comment: @RyanSchiller, in your code, what `let text = dict["comments"] as? [String:Any]` part does? I think this is your text.
Note: I'm assuming you parsing part is correct.

Comment: In code replace `let comment = Comment(id: childDataSnapshot.key, text: comments)` with `let comment = Comment(id: childDataSnapshot.key, text: text)`. That should work.

Comment: I changed parsing to have in the Comment class:                                                `static func parseComment(_ key:String, data:[String:Any]) -> Comment? {
        if let text = data["text"] as? String{
            return Comment(id: key, text: text)
        }
        
        
        return nil
    }  `   Then I added: `let data = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any], let post = Comment.parseComment(childSnapshot.key, data: data){
    tempComments.insert(post, at: 0)
                }
            }
            self.commentsTable.reloadData()
        })
    }`

Comment: This fixed the error, but we still have ' cell.set(comment: comments[indexPath.row])' error where the program wants to change comment to post.

Comment: In your stucture, why don't you have a */posts/post_0 and /posts/post_1* and then a separate comments node that contains comments for each post. It seems you have unneeded duplicate posts nodes and comments nodes. I am all about denormalizing but it may not be needed in this case. If you have a less deep structure it will make loading the comments for each post very simple.

Comment: That sounds like the structure I want. I am not sure how to implement that where each post gets its own number in the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on data in the question and then followup comments.

Denormalizing data is standard practice in NoSQL databases but in this case the structure in the question may be more complex than is needed.

Here's the question

> Given a series of posts where each post has comments, how do you load
>   the comments for each post to be displayed in a tableView.

I am going to work backward from a proposed structure

```
posts
   post_0 //created with .childByAutoId
      creator_uid: "the uid of whoever created this post"
      post_title: "My post about posting"

comments
   post_0 //ties back to the key of the post in the posts node
      comment_0 //created with .childByAutoId
         comment_by_uid: "whoever created this comment"
         comment_text: "comment about this post"
      comment_1
         comment_by_uid: "whoever created this comment"
         comment_text: "comment about this post"
```

This structure separates out the comments from the post they reference. Within the comments node, the key to each node is the post_id from the posts node. This allows the posts to be loaded in a tableView without a lot of overhead and if for example, you're displaying the comments in a detailView, load all of the comments for a specific post.

Note that posts nodes and comments node keys are created with .childByAutoId()

Now the workflow. Suppose a user is creating a new post and has entered a title for the post and other information. Call this to create the post in Firebase.

```
func createPost(withTitle: String, andCreatorUid: String) {
    let postsRef = self.ref.child("posts")
    let thisPost = postsRef.childByAutoId()
    let d = [
        "post_title": withTitle,
        "creator_uid": andCreatorUid
        ]
    thisPost.setValue(d)
}
```

Here's the tricky bit - what *I do* is have an observer of the posts node. When a new post is added, I receive that event, create a PostsClass object that contains info about the post and add that to my dataSource array, then refresh my tableView. By doing that, I am also getting the key to the node (which was created with .childByAutoId).

Another user sees that post and wants to comment on it so they tap the post to enter a comment. The follow code stores their comment in Firebase.

```
func addComment(toPostId: String, andComment: String, commentByUid: String) {
    let commentsRef = self.ref.child("comments") //ref to the comments node
    let thisCommentRef = commentsRef.child(toPostId) //ref to a node with postId as key
    let commentToAddRef = thisCommentRef.childByAutoId() //each comment will have it's own key
    let d = [
        "comment_text": andComment,
        "comment_by_uid": commentByUid]
    commentToAddRef.setValue(d)
}
```

toPostId is the key to the post which is obtained from the PostClass object they selected to add a comment to.

Finally, to specially answer the question, here's the loading of comments for a specific post.

```
func loadComments(forPostId: String) {
    let ref = self.ref.child("comments")
    let thisPostRef = ref.child(forPostId)
    thisPostRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        let allComments = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for commentSnap in allComments {
            let commenterUid = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "comment_by_uid").value as? String ?? "No uid"
            let commentText = commentSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "comment_text").value as? String ?? "No comment"
            //create a commentClass object, update properties and add to dataSourceArray
            print(commenterUid, commentText)
        }
        //tableView reload
    })
}
```

Notes:

I have a class var, *ref*, so self.ref points to my root firebase node. You will need to set that to point to yours

I am using post_0, and comment_0 as node key names in this answer as it's easier to read and understand than a key like *-LhzJD3tPL0xcnUDMaOZ* which is what .childByAutoId will actually create in your firebase.

Comment: The data structure looks good. I updated the post with my current code at the bottom. The tableView still will not load with comments. and now my commentPlaceHolder does not disappear when I type in the newCommentLabel textView. Is there a problem with my dataSource or my loading of the View? My debugging attempts have yielded no leads yet.

Comment: @RyanSchiller If you leave the `print(commenterUid, commentText`) line in the for loop, does it print those for each comment?

Comment: Yes it does print those in the terminal (I added this into the code in the post). The tables are empty however.

Comment: @RyanSchiller Are you certain the comments array is empty? In my last bit of code where I have the `//create a commentClass` you should be creating a comment class, and then `self.commentArray.insert...`. Then following the for loop (not inside it)  should have the tableView reload. Other than that, ensure you tableView has it's dataSource and delegate set. You may want to wire up a test button that you can click after you run the loadComments function to print out the contents of the array. It should not be empty.

Comment: When I tried the test button, `@IBAction func test(_ sender: UIButton) { print(comments)
    }` it prints out an empty array! Some how the comments are not making it out of the function and into the table. I will think more on this tomorrow. Is the view not loading or the id for the comments misassociated?

Comment: @RyanSchiller You've got a lot of unrelated code in your question, and I know the code in my answer works as I pulled it from an existing project. We are not really concerned with the table at the moment; if the dataSource array is empty, so will your tableView. You should generally reference class vars with self., and as your creating your commentsClass objects, they can be directly added to that array. So `let aComment = CommentClass(......)` and then `self.comment.append(aComment)`. Dont worry about ordering right now. I would suggest cleaning up and updating the question with current code.

Comment: I changed the OP text to make it easier for future coders to learn from. The only issue I have left is that the textViewDidChange function no longer works. Am I not calling it appropriately?

Comment: @RyanSchiller The ViewController needs to be a delegate for textVIews *as well as* tableViews, so it need to include UITableViewDelegate *and* UITextViewDelegate. The tableView delegate is the viewController and the textViews it contains *also* need to let the viewController know about changes within them so for each textView, assign its delegate to the viewController e.g. `myTextView.delegate = self`. see [textViewDidChange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidChange:)

Answer (score 0):

In this line `Comment(id: childDataSnapshot.key, text: comments)` you are passing comments (it is array property) but you need to pass text. To reload data use `commentsTable.reloadData()`.
For the error in `cellForRowAt` double check what you need to pass to configure your cell and check what type are you passing in `set(comment`

Comment: I am not sure how to call each comment text as each one is associated with a unique id like "-Lht1KEhkJR7ZPTcDqn8" or "-Lht1M76Bu9kTXJDezPp"

Comment: create dictionary like [uniqueId: comment text] and then just search by keys. Something like set(text: commentsDicrionary[uniqueId])

Comment: I think this would require restructuring my JSON. I tried to do this with comment = [Comment] ()  and I still cannot figure out how to pull the text strings themselves and not the comments as a type.